# Getting aspxerrorpath Error in URL - Path Exists - Why 404?

Tags: asp.net

I have a Redirect.aspx page. This page takes in parameters and redirects to the appropriate resource based on those parameters.

Another page sends a redirect to Redirect.aspx and I end up on the Default.aspx page with an aspxerrorpath=/myapp/Redirect.aspx.

I assume this means that I got a 404 error and that it means that it could not find the Redirect.aspx file. But I check the project directory and the file is there.

Any ideas on why my I am getting this error? Thanks!

Comment: This happened to me too. The exception caught was that the thread was aborted, possibly due to a time out, and was because a service we normally run wasn't running. Running the service fixed it as the thread no longer timed out. Possibly a similar thing is happening to you. I know it isn't an answer, but I hope that it helps in some way.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/net-141/asp-net-mvc-custom-error-page-statuscode-404-throws-500-a-663415.html).
The real catch was using this:

```
Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
```